# Independent random variables: Wrong computation result

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independendly, identically distributed random variables with values in $\{\pm 1\}$. Prove that $X,Y$ and $X\cdot Y$ are pairwise independent.

So we have to prove that $X$ and $X\cdot Y$ are independent, and $Y$ and $X \cdot Y$ are. I have trouble with this because the following observation seems to disprove that.

$$P(X=1, XY=1) = $$
$$P(\{X=1\} \cap (\{X=1, Y=1\} \cup \{X=-1, Y=-1\}) = $$
$$P(\{X=1\} \cap \{X=1, Y=1\}) = $$
$$P(X=1, Y=1) = $$
$$P(X=1)\cdot P(Y=1)$$

But we would need $P(X=1)\cdot P(XY=1)$ at the end, which is not the same since for the last factor of that, we could have $X=-1, \, Y=-1$, which however, was excluded in our calculation above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you written out the four elementary events?

Comment: The theorem is easy to verify if $P(X=1)=P(Y=1)=\frac12$, but it's not true in general. Have you tried coming up with a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing anything in wrong. As Karl said in the comments, this statement is false except in one special case. All you need to do to prove that is plug some numbers into your calculation.

Intuitively, if $P(X=1)> 1/2$, then if you know $X=1$ then it's more likely than before that $XY=1$, whereas if you know $X=-1$ it's more likely than before that $XY=-1$ (since it is more likely that $Y=1$ than $Y=-1$). Similar logic holds if $P(X=1)< 1/2.$

If $P(X=1)=P(X=-1) = 1/2$ then it is true $X$, $Y$ and $XY$ are pairwise independent, so perhaps that stipulation was intended for this exercise. Note that this is a pretty special case, and in general when $X$ is symmetric and $Y$ is independent from the same distribution, $X$ and $XY$ will be uncorrelated, but hardly ever independent. For instance if $P(X=-1)=P(X=1)=1/4$ and $P(X=0)= 1/2,$ it's easy to see $X$ and $XY$ aren't independent.